# Is the $S^1$ cone $D^2$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $Y=X \times [0,1]$ and $A=X \times \left \{ 0 \right \} \subset Y$. the cone on X is the space $\left \{ X \times [0,1] \right \}/\left \{ X \times \left \{ 0 \right \}  \right \}$.

Now let $X=S^1$, my goal is to prove that the cone on $X$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$, where $D^2$ is the unitary closed disk in $\Bbb R^2$.
Basically, this cone is obtained from a cylinder by contraction of the lower base to a point.

Using the polar coordinates we can establish a map $f: \left \{ X \times [0,1] \right \}/\left \{ X \times \left \{ 0 \right \}  \right \} \rightarrow D^2$ defined as $f(\theta, \rho)= \rho(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. 
This map is continuos, injective and surjective, but how to prove that is a homeomorphism?

Comment: The domain is compact and the codomain Hausdorff.

Comment: Can we say that $f$ is open, then is an homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, though it is easier to show $f$ is closed.  If $C$ is closed in the domain, then it must be compact.  Hence $f(C)$ is compact in the Hausdorff codomain, thus closed.

Comment: Ok, but how to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism without using the compactness?

Comment: Why do you not want to use that?  It's a standard trick that is frequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $f$ is a homeomorphism without using compactness, you can explicitly construct the inverse of $f$, namely
$$
g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]
$$
where brackets denote equivalence class, and
$$
t(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
0 & (x, y) = (0,0) \\
\frac{\pi}{2} & x = 0, y > 0\\
\frac{3\pi}{2} & x = 0, y < 0\\
\arctan(y/x) & x > 0 \\
\pi + \arctan(y/x) & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
where each of these values is to be considered a number (mod $2\pi$), hence an element of $S^1$.

The continuity of $g$ is pretty clear everywhere except along the $y$-axis. For those, you'll need to show that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U$ is open in the domain, which will mean writing down a way to describe open sets in the quotient, which is a pain in the neck, but you're welcome to do it.

Comment: This is more than enough. Thanks.

Comment: @John  Hughes sir    Imnot getting  why $y=[ \sqrt {x^2+y^2}]?$