# why $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]?$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I haven’t received any response from the user  So I'm posting this question

I have  some confusion in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886464/557708)

**Question** : Using the polar coordinates we can establish a map $f: \left \{ S^1 \times [0,1] \right \}/\left \{ S^1 \times \left \{ 0 \right \}  \right \} \rightarrow D^2$ defined as $f(\theta, \rho)= \rho(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. 
This map is continuos, injective and surjective, but

How to prove that is a homeomorphism?

I have  some confusion in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886464/557708)

Here  is the outline of  the  answer

> To show $f$ is a homeomorphism without using compactness, you can explicitly construct the inverse of $f$, namely
> $$
> g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]
> $$
> where brackets denote equivalence class, and
> $$
> t(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
> 0 & (x, y) = (0,0) \\
> \frac{\pi}{2} & x = 0, y > 0\\
> \frac{3\pi}{2} & x = 0, y < 0\\
> \arctan(y/x) & x > 0 \\
> \pi + \arctan(y/x) & x < 0
> \end{cases}
> $$
> where each of these values is to be considered a number (mod $2\pi$), hence an element of $S^1$.

> The continuity of $g$ is pretty clear everywhere except along the $y$-axis. For those, you'll need to show that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U$ is open in the domain, which will mean writing down a way to describe open sets in the quotient, which is a pain in the neck, but you're welcome to do it.

**My confusion** : Im not getting why $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$ ? I mean,  How  $y=[\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]?$

**My thinking** : Here $f(\theta, \rho)= \rho(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)=  te^{i \theta} $  where $t \in [0,1]$

$(\theta, \rho) = f^{-1}(te^{i \theta})$

According to the solution,$f^{-1}(te^{i \theta})=f^{-1}(t\cos\theta , t \sin \theta )=g(x,y)$ ,

$\implies  x= t \cos \theta ,y=\ t\sin \theta $

$\theta =[t(x,y)]$  and $\rho=[\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$

Comment: ok @azif00 Actually,  im not  getting how $ \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ come ? $ t \in [0,1]$ then why $t=   \sqrt {x^2+y^2}?$

Comment: $D^2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 1\}$.

Comment: okss that means  $0\le  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1\implies 0\le t\le 1$  Am  i right ? @azif00

Comment: Edit of my previous comment: The linked answer says: $[z,s] \in (S^1 \times [0,1])/(S^1 \times \{0\})$ will denote the equivalence class on the quotient of the point $(z,s) \in S^1 \times [0,1]$. What do you mean by writting things like $[t(x,y)]$ and $[\sqrt{x^2+y^2}]$? And, for your question in the title: that's the definition of $g$, it sends $(x,y) \in D^2$ to $[t(x,y), \sqrt{x^2+y^2}] \in (S^1 \times [0,1])/(S^1 \times \{0\})$.

Comment: You shouldn't use $t$ for a number in $[0,1]$, since $t$ already denotes the function described in the answer.

Comment: Ok , actually my confusion  was  on $y$ coordinate  of $[t(x,y) ,\sqrt {x^2+y^2}]$    so I write separately $[ \sqrt {x^2+y^2}]$ to state my confusion .  I thought  that $y= \sqrt {x^2 +y^2}$.Clearly, I was wrong.  @azif00