# why $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$ ? why not $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), 1-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I have  some confusion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886464/557708)

**Question** : Using the polar coordinates we can establish a map $f: \left \{ S^1 \times [0,1] \right \}/\left \{ S^1 \times \left \{ 0 \right \}  \right \} \rightarrow D^2$ defined as $f(\theta, \rho)= \rho(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. 
This map is continuos, injective and surjective, but

How to prove that is a homeomorphism?

Here  is the outline of  the  answer

> To show $f$ is a homeomorphism without using compactness, you can explicitly construct the inverse of $f$, namely
> $$
> g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]
> $$
> where brackets denote equivalence class, and
> $$
> t(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
> 0 & (x, y) = (0,0) \\
> \frac{\pi}{2} & x = 0, y > 0\\
> \frac{3\pi}{2} & x = 0, y < 0\\
> \arctan(y/x) & x > 0 \\
> \pi + \arctan(y/x) & x < 0
> \end{cases}
> $$
> where each of these values is to be considered a number (mod $2\pi$), hence an element of $S^1$.

> The continuity of $g$ is pretty clear everywhere except along the $y$-axis. For those, you'll need to show that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U$ is open in the domain, which will mean writing down a way to describe open sets in the quotient, which is a pain in the neck, but you're welcome to do it.

**My confusion** : Im not getting why $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$ ?  why not $g(x, y) = [t(x, y), 1-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}]$ ?

**My thinking** : Here  $\left \{ S^1 \times [0,1] \right \}/\left \{ S^1 \times \left \{ 0 \right \}  \right \} $  denote the cone $CS^1 $  of a topological space  $S^1$

where  $C= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 |z= 1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} ., 0 \le z \le 1\}$

That means $ g(x,y)=[(t(x,y) , 1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}]$

Comment: The answer has constructed an explicit inverse of $f$, namely, $g$. To confirm that it is indeed the inverse of $f$, you need to check that $g\circ f = f\circ g = \mathrm{id}$. If you try plugging in the $g$ you suggested, you'll see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that $f$ is a contiuous bijection, there is no need to write down the inverse. The domain of $f$ is compact and the range is Hausdorff, thus $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Here is remark concerning the definition of $f$:

Its seems that you take $S^1 = [0,2\pi]/\{0,2\pi\}$, otherwise the expression $\rho(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ does not make sense. But you certainly know that we also may take $S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2 = 1\}$. Then simply define $f((x,y),\rho) = \rho \cdot (x,y)$.